# React-native: setstate for the listview but object still return undefined

Tags: javascript, react-native

from the code below I try to make the dataSource return a String but it's return undefined

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
        uuid : this.props.navigation.state.params.uuid,
        facilityData: [],
        dataSource : []
    };
}

componentDidMount() {
    facilityStore.getFacilityInfo(this.state.uuid)
        .then((res) => {
            this.setState({
                facilityData: res.data.data
            })
            {this.checkparticipants()}
        })
        .catch((error) =>{
            alert(error);
        })
};

checkparticipants(){
    var ds = new ListView.DataSource({rowHasChanged: (r1,r2) => r1!=r2});
    this.setState({
        dataSource : ds.cloneWithRows([
            {invitePlaceholder : "Participant"},
            {invitePlaceholder : "Participant"},
            {invitePlaceholder : "Participant"},
            {invitePlaceholder : "Participant"},
        ])
    })
    console.log(this.state.dataSource.invitePlaceholder)
}
```

I want to render the textinput according to number of listview but there is an error which is:

> TypeError: undefined is not an object

```
<ListView
    dataSource = {this.state.dataSource}
    renderRow={(rowData)=>
        <TextInput style={styles.input}
            placeholder={rowData.invitePlaceholder}
        />
    }
/>
```

So what should I do to make the object not undefined from the code?

Answer (score 0):

`setState` is an asyncronous method. So, in order to have anything in state, I think you need to execute `checkParticipants` after the state is set. This is done as a callback of `setState`:

```
facilityStore.getFacilityInfo(this.state.uuid)
.then((res) => {
  this.setState({ facilityData: res.data.data }, this.checkparticipants)
})
```

Answer (score 0):

```
this.checkparticipants()
```

is not called because your syntax is wrong.
Your componentDidMount lifecycle should be:

```
componentDidMount() {
    facilityStore.getFacilityInfo(this.state.uuid)
        .then((res) => {
            this.setState({
                facilityData: res.data.data
            },
            () => this.checkparticipants());
        })
        .catch((error) =>{
            alert(error);
        });
}
```

`setState` is an asynchronous method. Call `checkparticipants()` after you have finished setting the state